# как узнать название фильма который отображается на страничке?

Tags: django

**У меня есть модель Movies, мне нужно добавить комменарий к фильму, а для этого узнать (название) какой именно фильм сейчас отображается на страничке, как это сделать?**

упрощенная models

```
class Movies(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Название", max_length=70)
```

упрощенная url

```
path('films/<int:pk>', views.MoviePageListView.as_view(), name='single-page')
```

views

```
class MoviePageListView(DetailView):
model = Movies
template_name = 'movies/show.html'
context_object_name = 'movie_pg'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ctx = super(MoviePageListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    
    ctx['news'] = news
    ctx['rat_movie'] = rat_movie
    return ctx
```

Comment: вам надо просто создать модель комментариев к фильму с привязкой через fk. Потом создать форму для комментариев и выводить ее на странице с фильмом

Comment: буду очень благодарен если покажете как

Comment: я пытался использовать fk, но не получилось создать под нее форму

Answer (score 0, accepted):

создать модель `Reviews`

```
class Reviews(models.Model):
    """Отзывы"""
    name = models.CharField("Имя", max_length=70)
    text = models.TextField("Сообщение", max_length=5000)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Movies, verbose_name="фильм", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Отзыв"
        verbose_name_plural = "Отзывы"
```

создать форму(файл forms.py)

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Форма отзывов"""
    class Meta:
        model = Reviews
        fields = ("name", "text")
```

Дальше добавить форму в `DetailView`

```
class MoviePageListView(DetailView):
    model = Movies
    template_name = 'movies/show.html'
    context_object_name = 'movie_pg'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(MoviePageListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['form'] = ReviewForm()
        ctx['news'] = news
        ctx['rat_movie'] = rat_movie
        return ctx
```

теперь осталось вывести форму. Для этого на странице с фильмом надо добавить

```
<h3>Оставить отзыв</h3>
<form action="{% url 'add_review' movie_pg.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>Ваш комментарий</label>
    <br>
    {{form}}
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

в этой строчке `<form action="{% url 'add_review' movie_pg.id %}" method="post">` указанно   на какой url отправлять обработку комментария.
Теперь создадим само обработку.
Создадим класс c методом `post`. В метода `pos`t передаем параметры`(self, request, pk)`. `Pk` нужен для привязки комментария к фильму. А сам `pk` мы получаем отсюда `movie_pg.id` пару строчек выше в form мы передали это значение.

```
class AddReview(View):
    """Отзывы"""
    def post(self, request, pk):
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
        movie = Movies.objects.get(id=pk)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.movie  = movie 
            form.save()
        return redirect('/')
```

последнем шагом останется добавить сам url.
В файл urls.py приложения добавить

```
path("review/<int:pk>/", views.AddReview.as_view(), name="add_review")
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало! Пойду искать как после добавления комента перекинуло обратно, а не на главную страницу